# React Native Expo Notifications Displaying Gray Square Instead of Specified Icon only via FCM

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a React Native application using Expo, which includes a chat feature where notifications are received via FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). Other app notifications are triggered locally using expo-notifications. Both local and FCM-targeted notifications use the same resource located at /assets/favicon.png.

The local notifications are displaying correctly, showing the intended logo (a transparent background PNG). However, after generating a build, FCM-triggered notifications show up as a gray square.

Is there any particular reason why the FCM notifications, unlike local notifications, are not displaying the intended icon but rather showing a gray square? How can I resolve this issue and ensure the FCM notifications display the correct icon as specified in the app.json configuration?

In my app.json, the notification property is configured as follows:

```
"notification": {
  "icon": "./assets/favicon.png"
}
```

Notification with the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/em7UI.png